# Modelling individual contribution over a fixed set of matchups

Tags: statistics

I apologize in advance if my question is too basic to be worthy of anyone's time, but stats are not part of my curriculum.

I am developping a proof of concept of a web application modelling the contribution of individual soccer player with respect to their successive teams over time. Fow now the goal is to use only the win rate of team A vs teams B over a fixed set of games and players to give a statistically significant ranking of:

- the best/worst combinations of players when playing in the same team in the same matches;
- the best/worst combinations players when playing in opposite teams in the same matches, i.e. which tuples of teammates are the best/worst against which;

I must admit I don't quite know how to approach the problem. Which methods or models could you suggest that would strike a decent balance between statistical adequacy and intellibility for someone curious to learn yet very naive in stats?

If you have any book chapter or readable resource to share, that would also be very appreciated.

Thanks!